# Saving metadata in Wordpress elements

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with meta of post in Wordpress. The problem is that under seemingly identical conditions, element e1 writes metadata, but element e2 does not. Any ideas on how to cure this? My functions are:

```
function r_func( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field (basename( __FILE__ ), 'e1' );
    wp_nonce_field (basename( __FILE__ ), 'e2' );
    $custom1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'e1', true );
    $custom2 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'e2', true );?>
    <label for="e1">CCC</label>
    <input name="e1" type="date" id="e1" value="<?php echo esc_attr($custom1); ?>">
    <p><label for="e2">LLL</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="e2" id="e2" value="<?php echo esc_attr($custom2); ?>"/></p>
    <?php }


function ev( $post_id, $post ) {
    if ( !isset( $_POST['e1'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['e1'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return $post_id;
    if ( !isset( $_POST['e2'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['e2'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return $post_id;
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'e2', $_POST['e2']);
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'e1', $_POST['e1']);
}
```

Function ev() is attached to a hook:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'ev', 10, 2 );
```

Same for r_func:

```
function add_mb( $post_type, $post ) {
    add_meta_box('meta1', 'My_meta', 'r_func', 'post', 'side', 'high');
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_mb', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Where abouts are you calling `ev()`?

Comment: I'm attaching this function to a hook: `add_action( 'save_post', 'ev', 10, 2 );` \n `
Same to r_func: `add_meta_box( 'meta1', 'My_meta', 'r_func', 'post', 'side', 'high' );`

Comment: `wp_nonce_field` _returns_ the HTML code for a nonce field, it doesn't output it. You don't output that return value either, so - your form doesn't appear to contain a nonce at all, and yet you are trying to verify them in `ev` ...? Currently I can't see how this would save _either_ of the two values.

Comment: I was using this guide: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/

Comment: @CBroe you right, I have a problem with both fields. Can you explain, please? I am using wp_nonce_field() in r_func(), which is hoocked to add_meta_boxes action. What is wrong with this? Function returns html code, which will be (I thing so) build in page. Why does this does not work?

Comment: A function _returning_ a value, does not mean _output_ gets created. For that to happen, you need to `echo` the returned value.

Comment: I tried `echo wp_nonce_field (basename( __FILE__ ), 'e1' );`, but that does not work.

Comment: I redirected wp_nonce_field to text field and get this inside:
<input type="hidden" id="e1" name="e1" value="02e44ab317" /><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/wp-admin/post.php?post=192&action=edit" />

Comment: @CBroe I did some experiments with page html source in browser and it turned out that if I use `echo`, html `tags'<input type="hidden" id="e1'.....` are shown twice for each field (e1 and e2), and if I don’t use `echo`, tags shown once. Are you sure that 'missing' `echo` is my problem?

Comment: Ah, my bad, the `$display` parameter for that function is true by default, so it will create output. But your text input fields have the same names as those nonce fields, `e1` and `e2` - so the resulting parameters will overwrite each other, when the form gets submitted. You need to name your nonce fields something else.

Comment: And nonces are not "field-based", as far as I know. So you should not be adding a nonce for each form field here, but only _one_ nonce for the entire form.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you, thats was my problem. Now everything works fine. Could you please format your comment as an answer so that I can select it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wp_nonce_field (basename( __FILE__ ), 'e1' );
...
<input name="e1" type="date" id="e1" value="<?php echo esc_attr($custom1); ?>">
...
```

Your text input fields have the same names as those nonce fields, `e1` and `e2` - so the resulting parameters will overwrite each other, when the form gets submitted. You need to name your nonce fields something else.

And nonces are not "field-based" - you should not be adding a nonce for each form field here, but only one nonce for the entire form.